# How to draw 2d and 3d text using opengl in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

First up all sorry for my English.

I started learning the opengl in android by reffering following link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

and also about drawing shapes by refering these 
links
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html

http://obviam.net/index.php/opengl-es-android-displaying-graphical-elements-primitives/

Now i turned to drawing 2d and 3d text using opengl in android but coluld not foun an perfect link for providing solution for drawing 2d and 3d text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text outside your OpenGL viewing area, you can place your GLSurfaceView within a layout, with the text in the other controls. This is the simplest option.

To place text *within* the GLSurfaceView, you either draw the individual characters as 3D ojbects and place them appropriately, or create a bitmap with the text you want and use it as the texture for a flat surface which you draw as part of your scene.